# Web extension converted from chrome to safari fails with error "The service_worker script failed to load due to an error."

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

As stated in the title, I am trying to convert a web extension originally made for chrome to safari, using the tool documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari

The project is created, builds, and launches successfully, however when the extension is enabled in safari I get 2 errors:

- "An extension with a non-persistent background page cannot listen to `webRequest` events."
- "The `service_worker` script failed to load due to an error."

The first error is a general bug in chromium, which is fixed in v107 (verified in chrome canary), and the extension relies on this API to work.

I have no idea what to do with the second error, as it provides no information at all. The option to access the background page process is disabled in the Safari Develop menu with the message "service worker failed to load".

Here is my "manifest.json"

```json
{
"name":"...",
"manifest_version":3,
"content_scripts":[{"all_frames":false,"js":["content.js"],"matches":["file://*/*","http://*/*","https://*/*"],"run_at":"document_idle","match_origin_as_fallback":true}],
"host_permissions":["<all_urls>"],
"permissions":["tabs","activeTab","storage","scripting","notifications","webRequest","downloads","alarms"],
"background":{"service_worker":"background.js"},
"content_security_policy":{"extension_pages":"script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"},
"web_accessible_resources":[{"resources":["inject.js"],"matches":["<all_urls>"]}],
"action":{"default_popup":"popup.html"},
"icons":{"16":"resources/icons/16x16.png","32":"resources/icons/32x32.png","48":"resources/icons/48x48.png","128":"resources/icons/128x128.png"},
"commands":{"_execute_action":{"suggested_key":{"default":"Shift+Alt+C"},"description":"Start the extension"}},
"version":"0.7.5",
"description":"...",
"author":"..."
}
```

Does anyone have any good suggestions/knowledge on how to debug why the service worker doesn't load? The extension works without any errors or warnings in Google Chrome.

Comment: There might be a way to enable a debug logging in Safari e.g. start it from terminal with a special command line. You can try putting `webRequest` into `optional_permissions` and then use chrome.permissions API. Another thing to try is to cut the background script in halves recursively until it starts working: the problem will be in the last excluded half.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to be with 2 API's that I use: `storage.session` and `webRequest`. Storage errors disappeared when using `storage.local` instead. Sadly, it didn't seem to help putting it in `optional_permissions`. I guess I'll have to wait until safari supports the `webRequest` API in manifest v3.

Thanks for the suggestion either way.

Comment: @SørenBruusZeppelin just wondering if you reported the storage.session bug to Apple, and if using storage.local has permanently stopped the service worker crashes?

Comment: @SørenBruusZeppelin, Is there a way to find out what is the error by which its failing? any console logs etc... network tab,as in chrome, the extension console opens up seperately which is used to debug if this is the same with safari, can anyone provide instructions to debug!

Answer (score 0):

The `webRequest` api doesn't seem to be available in safari when using manifest v3, and is a blocking issue, meaning the problem cannot currently be solved.

Furthermore `storage.session` also caused the service worker to crash, but this could be mitigated by using `storage.local` instead.

Will have to wait and see if safari supports the `webRequest` API in the future.

Comment: have you tried using `fetch`

Comment: Not trying to make an http request. My extension needs to listen to requests being made in the browser

Comment: How did you debug this issue? I can't find a way to get any logs and my extension is also failing with "The service_worker script failed to load due to an error."

Comment: I couldn't find a good way to debug it, so I took @wOxxOm's advice and started commenting out code until I had something that worked, then zoomed in on the specific issues from there.

Comment: Have there been any updates to this issue? I seem to be encountering the same thing today. I have a chrome web extension i converted to safari, everything works but the service-worker fails to load. If anyone has insight on how best to diagnose this issue I'd appreciate it. Also if you have an example tutorial video of service-worker in safari extension, that would be helpful thanks